# Netbeans warning: no enabled eligible for injection beans are found

Tags: jsf, netbeans, warnings, observer-pattern, cdi

I have two beans. **First** bean languageOfSystem:

```
@Named(value = "languageOfSystem")
@SessionScoped
public class LanguageOfSystem implements Serializable {
   @Inject private JsfUtils eeJsfUtils;
```

and the **second** bean, userBb:

```
@Named(value = "userBb")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBb implements Serializable, LangUpdInterface {
   @EJB
   private EjbUtils ejbUtils;
   @EJB
   private PuserFacade puserFacade;
   @Inject
   private Direction direction;
   @Inject
   private PortfelDao portfelDao;
   @Inject
   private LanguageOfSystem languageOfSystem;
```

I inject `languageOfSystem` into `userBb`, and NetBeans IDE gives me warning in line with that injection:

```
no enabled eligible for injection beans are found
```

But I'm able to call methods from `languageOfSystem` in `userBb` and it works fine. So is this warning important and should I change smth?

And the second question. I use in this case [observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), where `userBb` is dependent and `languageOfSystem` is the subject which has a list of dependents. I register `userBb` in subject list by calling appropriate method from `languageOfSystem`. Is it right when it comes to the two session beans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I'm able to call methods from languageOfSystem in userBb and it
>   works fine.

Your code does not look wrong - and it works. So this seems to be a Netbeans issues.

> And the second question. I use in this case observer design pattern,
>   where userBb is dependent and languageOfSystem is the subject which
>   has a list of dependents. I register userBb in subject list by calling
>   appropriate method from languageOfSystem. Is it right when it comes to
>   the two session beans?

Are you aware that the CDI spec includes a powerful and [typesafe implementation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/events.html) of the observer pattern? You definitely should check this out.

And two more things to mention here:

```
@Named(value = "languageOfSystem")
@Named(value = "userBb")
```

1. The value you are providing is already default. So you can leave it
   out and simply write `@Named` instead.
2. Regarding the code you are posting: `@Named` is not required at all -
   all it does is providing an EL name for use in JSF. Your code will
   work just as good if you skip @Named altogether...

Comment: I use methods from both beans in jsf pages, so I need @Named annotation. You're right about leaving (value = "smth"). I just have no conviction about "what is the best practice" so in my case it was obsolete, something like a comment. Relating to cdi typesafe implementation, it looks promising but a little enigmatic for me. I'd love a working example. But I'll try to understand it.

Comment: Wow :o) I did it. I mean I used observer pattern from cdi. It's a little different than pure pattern, but quite simple, useful and powerful. It gives even more loose coupling than pure solution. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

As to your first question:

This is a known netbeans bug (see [here](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201825#c6) and [here](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=205914)). However, the discussion in the first link indicates that it is rather an issue of the weld implementation and Netbeans' warning is according to the specification.

Nevertheless the bugzilla file says it will be fixed in Netbeans v7.2.

Until then you can still disable the warning (*Tools --> Options --> Editor --> Hints*)

Comment: This can be seen in NetBeans 8.0 too.

Comment: I have the same annoying warning using NetBeans 8.0.2 and `@Inject` along with `@Param` from Omnifaces.